# resize browser and menubar getting hidden inside header

Tags: html, css

When I re-sized my browser, my menu bar getting hidden inside the header.. not understanding what to change values exactly in CSS files...
I am not a good coder in css, just had  a little knowledge in it..
here is the site: `http://dfgdsgdgdg.com/`
I have even tried changing values from pixels to percentages, BUT still not understanding...
**below are the files i changed values in it:**

```
http://dgdgfg.com/wp-content/themes/emporium/styles/green.css
http://ghdgfhdhgfgh.com/wp-content/themes/emporium/style.css
http://dgfhdghgh.com/wp-content/themes/emporium/css/layout.css?ver=3.5
```

Could anyone please look into and solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Give your top section a height and you're set.

```
section.top{
  height:100px;
}
```

Comment: I just used our code, it little works.. but still one of images going somewhere. i need one image left and otehr image right, could you please look into again bro, here: articlewritingservicess.com

Answer (score 0):

change in  line 248 in style.css

```
        img, embed, object, video {   
         max-width: 25%;
         height: auto;
      }
```

or

```
       <div class="col-1 description" style="height: 25px;">
```